# find the line number where a specific word appears with “sed” on tcl shell

Tags: sed, cygwin, tcl, 32-bit

I need to search for a specific word in a file starting from specific line and return the line numbers only for the matched lines.

Let's say I want to search a file called `myfile` for the word `my_word` and then store the returned line numbers.

By using shell script the command :

```
sed -n '10,$ { /$my_word /= }' $myfile
```

works fine but how to write that command on tcl shell?

```
% exec  sed -n '10,$ { /$my_word/= }' $file
```

extra characters after close-brace.

I want to add that the following command works fine on tcl shell but it starts from the beginning of the file

% exec sed -n "/$my_word/=" $file

447431
447445
448434
448696
448711
448759
450979
451006
451119
451209
451245
452936
454408

I have solved the problem as follows

```
set lineno 10
if { !  [catch {exec sed -n "/$new_token/=" $file} lineFound] && [string length $lineFound] > 0 } {
set lineNumbers [split $lineFound "\n"]
foreach num $lineNumbers {
    if {[expr {$num >= $lineno}] } {
        lappend col $num
    }   
}
   }
```

Still can't find a single line that solve the problem

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Its not clear if you like to search for `my_word` or the value stored in variable `$my_word`. In your text you does mention search for word `my_word` and in example you are using `my_word` as a variable name.

Comment: I'm searching for the value stored in $my_word

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand a thing: is the text you are looking for stored inside the variable called `my_word` or is the literal value `my_word`?

In your line

```
% exec  sed -n '10,$ { /$my_word/= }' $file
```

I'd say it's the first case. So you have before it something like

```
% set my_word wordtosearch
% set file    filetosearchin
```

Your mistake is to use the single quote character `'` to enclose the sed expression. That character is an enclosing operator in `sh`, but has no meaning in Tcl.

You use it in `sh` to group many words in a single argument that is passed to `sed`, so you have to do the same, but using Tcl syntax:

```
% set my_word wordtosearch
% set file    filetosearchin
% exec sed -n "10,$ { /$my_word/= }" $file
```

Here, you use the `"..."` to group.

You don't escape the `$` in `$my_word` because you want `$my_word` to be substitued with the string `wordtosearch`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marco, I have followed your steps, but I got the following error                                                       $ tclsh
% set my_word afe_drx_m0_in
afe_drx_m0_in
% set file dmodem_default.v
dmodem_default.v
% exec sed -n "10,\$ \{ /$my_word/= \}" $file
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: `\'

Comment: I want also to add that I'm using tcl under Cygwin

Comment: I think I made a mistake: the `{` and `}` shouldn't be escaped. I'm editing the answer right now.

Comment: same error 
% exec sed -n "10,\$ { /$my_word/= }" $file
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: `\'

Comment: You don't need a backslash before the `$`; there's a space after it, so it isn't special.

Answer (score 0):

After a few trial-and-error I came up with:

```
set output [exec sed -n "10,\$ \{ /$myword/= \}" $myfile]
# Do something with the output
puts $output
```

The key is to escape characters that are special to TCL, such as the dollar sign, curly braces.

## Update

Per Donal Fellows, we do not need to escape the dollar sign:

```
set output [exec sed -n "10,$ \{ /$myword/= \}" $myfile]
```

I have tried the new revision and found it works. Thank you, Donal.

## Update 2

I finally gained access to a Windows 7 machine, installed Cygwin (which includes sed and tclsh). I tried out the above script and it works just fine. I don't know what your problem is. Interestingly, the same script failed on my Mac OS X system with the following error:

```
sed: 1: "10,$ { /ipsum/= }": extra characters at the end of = command
    while executing
"exec sed -n "10,$ \{ /$myword/= \}" $myfile"
    invoked from within
"set output [exec sed -n "10,$ \{ /$myword/= \}" $myfile]"
    (file "sed.tcl" line 6)
```

I guess there is a difference between Linux and BSD systems.

## Update 3

I have tried the same script under Linux/Tcl 8.4 and it works. That might mean Tcl 8.4 has nothing to do with it. Here is something else that might help: Tcl comes with a package called `fileutil`, which is part of the *tcllib*. The `fileutil` package contains a useful tool for this case: `fileutil::grep`. Here is a sample on how to use it in your case:

```
package require fileutil
proc grep_demo {myword myfile} {
    foreach line [fileutil::grep $myword $myfile] {
        # Each line is in the format:
        # filename:linenumber:text
        set lineNumber [lindex [split $line :] 1]
        if {$lineNumber >= 10} { puts $lineNumber}
    }
}

puts [grep_demo $myword $myfile]
```

Comment: Thanks Hai, but still not working on my tcl shell under Cygwin. the following illustrate my trails .... $ tclsh
% set my_word afe_drx_m0_in
afe_drx_m0_in
% set file dmodem_postroute_default.v
dmodem_postroute_default.v
% exec sed -n "10,$ \{ /$my_word/= \}" $file
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: `\'
%

Comment: Must be some differences between a Linux system (Ubuntu 13.10) and Cygwin. I am sorry I dont have a Windows machine to try it out.

Comment: @HaiVu: I agree. My first try, which was identical to yours, was working on Linux.

Comment: Thank you a lot Marco and Hai, I have edited my question with a workaround to solve the problem, still not the optimum one but it works fine

Comment: Please see my update 2. It looks like my code works on Cygwin 64-bit + Windows 7

Comment: Thanks Hai for keeping help and support, I tried the command on Windows7 + Cygwin64 bit and it works fine , but the issue I'm trying to solve is on Windows XP and Cygwin 32bit , I believe Cygwin 32bit is using an older tcl version tcl8.4 while Cygwin64bit is using tcl8.5

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk 'NR>10 && $0~f {print NR}' f="$my_word" "$myfile"
```

This search for all line larger than line number `10` that contains word in variable `$my_word` in file name stored in variable `myfile`

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but this syntax could work on unix shell, I need a one that works on tcl sh                                       % exec awk 'NR>10 && $0~f {print NR}' f="$token" "$file"
extra characters after close-brace

Comment: This is plain `awk` and should work in nearly all `linux/unix` distro out there.  I do not understand what you say is wrong.  Give an output example.  `awk` is a program itself and just returns its value back to shell (bash/tcl)

Comment: ya Jotne you are right your command "awk 'NR>10 && $0~f {print NR}' f="$token" "$file""   as well as my sed command "sed -n '10,$ { /$my_word /= }' $myfile"  works successfully on unix/linux shell ,  but to write such command on tcl shell , you have to take into consideration the tcl shell "special characters",  my problem is how to convert your command or my command to something acceptable by the tcl shell

Comment: I have edited my question to have a working command on the tcl shell but it starts from the beginning of the file not from a specific line

Comment: Sorry, but OP asked how to execute the `sed` command she has from a Tcl shell, and not how to do the same task using another scripting language.